# Unknown column 'eav_attribute.slug' using django-eav

Tags: django

I am trying to use django-eav and am running into a problem where the slug field is not present in one of the eav tables.

```
>>> import eav
>>> eav.register(MyModel)
>>> from eav.models import Attribute
>>> Attribute.objects.create(name='Weight', datatype=Attribute.TYPE_FLOAT)
```

results in:

```
DatabaseError: (1054, "Unknown column 'eav_attribute.slug' in 'where clause'")
```

At first I used South migrations but ran into a similar problem when it tried to add a constraint on slug and another column, resulting in the migration failing because of the missing column. For the test above, I did not use South migrations.

Any suggestions on why the slug field isn't being created?